# import.meta.glob() can only accept string literals

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vite

I have a vite vue3 project. In the component I try to get the URL of all images from a folder.  It works when I write

```
const images = import.meta.globEager("/src/resources/projects/images/Project1/*.png")
```

and in a template

```
<img v-for="(item, key) in images" :key="key" :src="key" />
```

but each component has a different folder and when I write

```
const imageFolderUrl = "/src/resources/projects/images/" + this.projectName + "/*.png";
const image = import.meta.globEager (imageFolderUrl);
```

i get the error `import.meta.glob()` can only accept string literals".
How can I load all images url from folder with a dynamic folder name?

Comment: You could attempt to load all resources for all projects with `/src/resources/projects/images/*/*.png`.

Answer (score 5):

I was trying to do the same thing with Sveltekit.

There's info at https://github.com/vitejs/vite/issues/5478

A quick workaround is to write any possible foldername as one possiblity in a switch/case statement.

```js
let images;
switch (imageFolderUrl) {
  case "Project1": images = import.meta.globEager("/src/resources/projects/images/Project1/*.png");
  case "Project2": images = import.meta.globEager("/src/resources/projects/images/Project2/*.png");
  ...
}
```

It's far from pretty, but it works if all you want is to avoid importing all `/**/*.png` and filtering down by path.