# Using Inertia in a Modularised Laravel app

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, inertiajs

Inertia is working nicely in my Laravel App.  I've set it up as per the Inertia pages, not entirely dissimilar to [this >>](https://dev.to/geowrgetudor/setting-up-laravel-with-inertiajs-vuejs-tailwind-css-21pc) guide (though there are significant differences in my app).

I'm in the process of trying to [modularise >>](https://docs.laravelmodules.com/v10/introduction) my app, which again I have no issues with in principle.  the Modules functionality works nicely.

The issue I'm having is that I'd like to build my Vue logic inside each of my modules' "Resources" directory.  When I have many modules, this means that the source Vue code will be spread over many "Modules", meaning that the `resolve()` function (in the JS script below) needs to check different locations for the files.

I found [this SO >>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72077023/import-meta-glob-can-only-accept-string-literals) post on how to "discover" Vue files from different locations.  Because `import.meta.glob` won't accept dynamic values, it has to be executed via a `switch` or complex array of `if` statements (or whatever). This much is fine as well.  If I switch the `moduleVar` parameter for a hard-coded value in the code below, I can load files from different modules (a few pseudo-cody glitches notwithstanding - code has been simplified to illustrate my problem).

**The problem is** that I can't find a way to pass the `moduleVar` parameter into the `resolve()` function.  Conceptually, what I'd like to do is the following:

```js
createInertiaApp({
  id: 'app',
  resolve: async(name, moduleVar) => { // moduleVar is pseudo-code. I can't find a way to actually pass a parameter in here
    const dirs = {
      'appfnd': () => import.meta.glob('../../Modules/appfnd/Resources/assets/js/vue/**/*.vue'),
      'sales':  () => import.meta.glob('../../Modules/sales/Resources/assets/js/vue/**/*.vue',
      'std':    () => import.meta.glob('./vue/**/*.vue'),
    };
    const pages = dirs[moduleVar](); // if I hard-code moduleVar to (e.g.) 'sales' my app works
    let page;
    switch (moduleVar) {
      case 'appfnd':
      case 'sales':
        page = (await pages[`../../Modules/${moduleVar}/Resources/assets/js/vue/${name}.vue`]()).default;
        break;
      default:
        page = (await pages[`./vue/${name}.vue`]()).default;
    }

    if (page.layout === undefined) {
      page.layout = Layout;
    }
    return page;
  },
  setup({ el, App, props, plugin }) {
    createApp({ render: () => h(App, props) })
      .use(plugin)
      .use(store)
      .use(ZiggyVue, Ziggy)
      .component('Head', Head)
      .component('Link', Link)
      .mount(el);
  },
  title: (title) => title + " - My Lovely App",
});
```

My idea is that the value would be passed in from Laravel's Controller, something like this:

```php
<?php

namespace Modules\AppFoundation\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Inertia\Inertia;

class PersonController extends Controller
{
    private $module = 'appfnd';

    public function fnFromLaravelRouter() {
        // `moduleVar` parameter in line below, matches variable name that I'd like to pick up in the JS code above.
        // This doesn't actually work, but hopefully illustrates what I'd like to achieve
        return Inertia::render('modules/appfnd/MyVueFile', ['moduleVar',$this->module]);
    }
}
```

The `name` parameter inside the JS `resolve()` function is the name of the file passed in from `Inertia::render()`, which in the above example is `'modules/appfnd/MyVueFile'`.  What I could do is to perform some string manipulation on this value, essentially passing in the data I want via a hack.  But I want to know if there's a better way to achieve what I want.

Hopefully I've explained clearly enough!

Answer (score 1):

I use '::' to separate module name and path to Vue page. It allows me to use Inertia like this:

```php
// Modules/Core/routes/web.php

Route::get('/member/categories', function () {
    return inertia('Core::Categories/Index', []);
})->name('member.categories.index');
```

To search page in correct place (in module in my case), use custom resolver for `createInertiaApp` function in `app.ts` file.

```
// app.ts
...
createInertiaApp({
    title: (title) => `${title} - ${appName}`,
    // resolve: (name) => resolvePageComponent(`./Pages/${name}.vue`, import.meta.glob<DefineComponent>('./Pages/**/*.vue')), // Comment this
    resolve: (name) => resolveVuePage(name), // Past this
    setup({ el, App, props, plugin }) {
...
```

Finaly, I create separate function to resolve pages

```
// page-resolver.ts

import {resolvePageComponent} from "laravel-vite-plugin/inertia-helpers";
import {DefineComponent} from "vue";

export function resolveVuePage(name: string):Promise<any> {
    console.log(name)
    const parts: string[] = name.split('::')
    if (parts.length > 1) {
        const modules = import.meta.glob('../../Modules/**/Pages/**/*.vue')
        const modulePath: string[] = Object.keys(modules)
        const modulePages: { [key: string]: string } = {}
        modulePath.map((path: string): void => {
            const pathParts: string[] = path.replace('../../Modules/', '')
                .split('/')
            const moduleName: string = pathParts.shift() as string
            // @ts-ignore
            const pageName: string = pathParts.slice(3)
                .join('/')
                .replace('.vue', '')
            const key: string = `${moduleName}::${pageName}`
            modulePages[key] = path
        })
        if (Object.keys(modulePages).includes(name)) {
            const path = modulePages[name]
            return resolvePageComponent(path, import.meta.glob<DefineComponent>('../../Modules/**/Pages/**/*.vue'))
        }
    }
    return resolvePageComponent(`./Pages/${name}.vue`, import.meta.glob<DefineComponent>('./Pages/**/*.vue'))
}
```

Hope this help.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  It's useful to know how other people resolve these kinds of issues.  Oddly enough (although I don't use type-script and my code is structured a little differently), my solution was (in principle) pretty much identical.  I also decided to used `::` as a separator between module and page so that the page-resolver could work out which module to find the `directory/page.vue` file in.  Great minds, and all that...! ;-)